# Azure Function in Docker container

Tags: docker, azure-functions

I'm Running HTTP Azure function V2 inside a docker container, I used [dockerfile](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/blob/master/src/Azure.Functions.Cli/StaticResources/Dockerfile.dotnet) to build my container and it's running but have many doubts

Why AzureFunction docker file is different from .netcore web project docker file, There is no **ENTRYPOINT** how it is running?

When we are using HTTP Trigger function in docker Linux container, Is it running through some webServer or self-host? I believe it self hosted. am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant base Dockerfile should be this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/blob/master/host/2.0/alpine/amd64/dotnet.Dockerfile

As you can see there, the WebHost is getting started - which also should answer your second question: Yes, it's a selfhost

```
CMD [ "/azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In general, we use Enterpoint command (.net core, Python) in the docker file, why azure function docker file is different, any idea?